# Customised listview to display json parsed data using custom adapter

Tags: android, list, listview, custom-lists

In custom_liststyle.xml I have listView  And in the another xml i have
 defined the view's which are to be inflated to the listView  here is
 the code of xmls

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvmov"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

These are in the Linear layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#8b8878"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imv1"
    android:layout_width="102dp"
    android:layout_height="102dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
</ImageView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="102dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/video_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#cccccc"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/video_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/duration"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:shadowColor="#cccccc" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewcounts"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/published"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have the pojo class for getter and setter called Moviepojo

```
package com.example.newlistidmedia;

import java.io.Serializable;

import android.net.Uri;

public class Moviepojo implements Serializable {
    private String ID;
    private String video_id;
    private String video_name;
    private String duration;
    private Uri image;
    private String viewcount;
    private String published;

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(String iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }

    public String getVideo_id() {
        return video_id;
    }

    public void setVideo_id(String video_id) {
        this.video_id = video_id;
    }

    public String getVideo_name() {
        return video_name;
    }

    public void setVideo_name(String video_name) {
        this.video_name = video_name;
    }

    public String getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(String duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public Uri getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Uri image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getViewcount() {
        return viewcount;
    }

    public void setViewcount(String viewcount) {
        this.viewcount = viewcount;
    }

    public String getPublished() {
        return published;
    }

    public void setPublished(String published) {
        this.published = published;
    }

}
```

And the Adapter to inflate the view of custom_stylelist

```
package com.example.newlistidmedia;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MovieAddapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context ct;
    List<Moviepojo> moviel;

    public MovieAddapter(Context ct, List<Moviepojo> moviel){   // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.ct = ct;
        this.moviel = moviel;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return moviel.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater lif = (LayoutInflater) ct.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = lif.inflate(R.layout.movie_list, null);
        ImageView imv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imv1);
        TextView tvid = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.id);
        TextView tvvid = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.video_id);
        TextView tvvname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.video_name);
        TextView tv_dur = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.duration);
        TextView tv_con = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.viewcounts);
        TextView tv_pub = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.published);
        Moviepojo mp = moviel.get(arg0);
        mv.setImageURI(mp.getImage());
        tvid.setText(mp.getID());
        tvvid.setText(mp.getVideo_id());
        tvvname.setText(mp.getVideo_name());
        tv_dur.setText(mp.getDuration());
        tv_con.setText(mp.getViewcount());
        tv_pub.setText(mp.getPublished());
        return v;
    }
}
```

and the movielist to parse json

The problem is the code looks correct but the json parsed is not
 visible on the list

```
package com.example.newlistidmedia;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MovieList extends Activity {
    List<Moviepojo> moviel;
    MovieAddapter ma;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cutom_liststyle);
        moviel = new Vector<Moviepojo>();
        ma = new MovieAddapter(this, moviel);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvmov);
        lv.setAdapter(ma);
        new TheTask().execute();
    }

    class TheTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<Moviepojo>> {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Moviepojo> result) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (moviel != null) {
                moviel.clear();
                moviel.addAll(result);
                ma.notifyDataSetChanged();
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Moviepojo> doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                HttpClient hct = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet hget = new

                HttpGet("http:xyz");
                HttpResponse hres = hct.execute(hget);
                if (hres.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                    String sjosns = EntityUtils.toString(hres.getEntity());
                    JSONArray jaary = new JSONArray(sjosns);
                    List<Moviepojo> mpojo = new Vector<Moviepojo>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < jaary.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jso = jaary.getJSONObject(i);

                        String ID = jso.getString("ID");
                        String video_id = jso.getString("video_id");
                        String video_name = jso.getString("video_name");
                        String duration = jso.getString("duration");
                        // Uri
                        // imagegetContentResolver().uncanonicalize("image");
                        String viewcount = jso.getString("viewcount");
                        String published = jso.getString("published");
                        Moviepojo m = new Moviepojo();
                        m.setID(ID);
                        m.setVideo_id(video_id);
                        m.setVideo_name(video_name);
                        m.setDuration(duration);
                        // m.setImage(image);
                        m.setViewcount(viewcount);
                        m.setPublished(published);
                        mpojo.add(m);

                    }
                    return mpojo;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}

         Help out me to view the parsed data on the list view
```

Comment: Try to print the parsed data in log

Comment: run in debug mode and check if data is being set to each view properly

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your logic

```
if (moviel != null) {

}
```

You are checking to see if moviel is null but in you onCreate you initializing it

```
moviel = new Vector<Moviepojo>();
```

So by definition it can not be null.

What you should be doing is checking its length to be 0.

Comment: Thanks for all for healping me out

Comment: My another question is if see the my pojo class i have image geter and setter .. even my json provide me a image string url .. helm me out to set that image on image view

Comment: Use an image library like https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader and pass in your imageview and your image url to it